# How do I get ConfigSlurper to use a calculated property in an environment

Tags: groovy, config

I want to have a groovy config that allows me to set some defaults (i.e. calculated values) that can be optionally overridden by environment. The following script shows a simple example.

```
import static junit.framework.Assert.*

def config = 
"""
base { value = "X" }
calc { value = base.value }

environments {
    overridebase {
        base { value = "1" }
    }
}
"""

// these asserts work
assertEquals("X", new ConfigSlurper().parse(config).base.value)
assertEquals("X", new ConfigSlurper().parse(config).calc.value)
assertEquals("1", new ConfigSlurper("overridebase").parse(config).base.value)

// this assert fails as calc.value remains "X"
assertEquals("1", new ConfigSlurper("overridebase").parse(config).calc.value)
```

The first three assertions work, so the original calculated value works but it appears to resolve too soon as it stays the original calculated value even when the base is changed.

Comment: I fear you have to add `calc { value = base.value }` inside `environments` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately that would defeat the purpose

Answer (score 0):

Proving myself wrong:

```
def myConfig = new ConfigSlurper("overridebase").parse(config)
assert "1" == Eval.me("${myConfig.calc.value}", myConfig.base.value, myConfig.calc.value.toString())
```

You encouraged me not to defeat the purpose. Thank You. :)

Comment: Beauty of [Eval](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html) API and have a look at some [examples](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-simple-evaluation-of.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the simplest thing to do is to just check for a missing value manually

```
import static junit.framework.Assert.*

def configs = 
"""
base { value = "X" }
calc {  }

environments {
    overridebase {
        base { value = "1" }
    }
    overridecalc {
        calc { value = "2" }
    }
}
"""

def config

config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(configs)

assertEquals("X", config.base.value)
assertEquals("X", config.calc.value ?: config.base.value)

config = new ConfigSlurper("overridebase").parse(configs)

assertEquals("1", config.base.value)
assertEquals("1", config.calc.value ?: config.base.value)

config = new ConfigSlurper("overridecalc").parse(configs)

assertEquals("X", config.base.value)
assertEquals("2", config.calc.value ?: config.base.value)
```

Comment: Aren't we defeating the purpose here? We no more have the calculated value of `calc` which you had in the question earlier. Why do we even need `config.calc.value`? :)

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I was hoping to not need to do anything in the code but I can't get that working. Even some meta-processing would be ok but at least this solution works in a way that won't confuse my non-groovy co-workers

Comment: Aren't groovy co-workers made more groovier by exposing to the groodness of Groovy?